# Is the system processor available in CMakePreset.json?

Tags: cmake, cmake-presets

Visual Studio generated the following CMakePresets.json for me when I click on "Manage Configurations..." in a CMake project:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "windows-base",
      "description": "Target Windows with the Visual Studio development environment.",
      "hidden": true,
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/build/${presetName}",
      "installDir": "${sourceDir}/out/install/${presetName}",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_C_COMPILER": "cl.exe",
        "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "cl.exe"
      },
      "condition": {
        "type": "equals",
        "lhs": "${hostSystemName}",
        "rhs": "Windows"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "x64-debug",
      "displayName": "x64 Debug",
      "description": "Target Windows (64-bit) with the Visual Studio development environment. (Debug)",
      "inherits": "windows-base",
      "architecture": {
        "value": "x64",
        "strategy": "external"
      },
      "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug" }
    },
    {
      "name": "x64-release",
      "displayName": "x64 Release",
      "description": "Target Windows (64-bit) with the Visual Studio development environment. (RelWithDebInfo)",
      "inherits": "x64-debug",
      "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release" }
    },
    {
      "name": "x86-debug",
      "displayName": "x86 Debug",
      "description": "Target Windows (32-bit) with the Visual Studio development environment. (Debug)",
      "inherits": "windows-base",
      "architecture": {
        "value": "x86",
        "strategy": "external"
      },
      "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug" }
    },
    {
      "name": "x86-release",
      "displayName": "x86 Release",
      "description": "Target Windows (32-bit) with the Visual Studio development environment. (RelWithDebInfo)",
      "inherits": "x86-debug",
      "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release" }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm interested in the cmake install prefix, which is set with the `installDir` field. It is nice because the resulting directory will indirectly include the processor name "x64" since the preset name includes the processor.

But the processor name is hardcoded, i.e. it is part of the string literal, e.g. `"x64-debug"`, in the various preset names. **Is it possible to reference the processor as a variable (or macro expansion) in CMakePresets.json?** I.e. something similar to the `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` cache variable that is available in CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Two things: (1) `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` is **not** a cache variable and (2) `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` may be set by the toolchain file, so the preset cannot possibly know what it will be.

Comment: @AlexReinking - "CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR is not a cache variable" -- this has thrown a wrench into the mental model I'd been building...but oh well, better to fix things earlier than later. Could you expand on that in an answer/comment? If it is not a cache variable, then what is it? It is automagically "available" to me in CMakeLists.txt without me explicitly setting it. I thought that's what a cache variable _was_: akin to "global variables", available to all CMakeLists.txt, some set automatically be CMake, but also user-creatable. (I can ask as a separate question if appropriate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. The full list of available macros can be found [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#macro-expansion).

It is currently limited to

- `${sourceDir}`: Path to the project source directory (i.e. the same as `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`).
- `${sourceParentDir}`: Path to the project source directory's parent directory.
- `${sourceDirName}`: The last filename component of `${sourceDir}`. For example, if `${sourceDir}` is `/path/to/source`, this would be `source`.
- `${presetName}`: Name specified in the preset's `name` field.
- `${generator}`: Generator specified in the preset's `generator` field. For build and test presets, this will evaluate to the generator specified by `configurePreset`.
- `${hostSystemName}`:The name of the host operating system. Contains the same value as `CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME`. This is allowed in preset files specifying version 3 or above.
- `${fileDir}`: Path to the directory containing the preset file which contains the macro. This is allowed in preset files specifying version 4 or above.
- `${dollar}`: A literal dollar sign ($).
- `${pathListSep}`: Native character for separating lists of paths, such as `:` or `;`. For example, by setting `PATH` to `/path/to/ninja/bin${pathListSep}$env{PATH}`, `${pathListSep}` will expand to the underlying operating system's character used for concatenation in `PATH`.
  This is allowed in preset files specifying version 5 or above.
- `$env{<variable-name>}`: Environment variable with name `<variable-name>`. The variable name may not be an empty string. If the variable is defined in the `environment` field, that value is used instead of the value from the parent environment. If the environment variable is not defined, this evaluates as an empty string. Note that while Windows environment variable names are case-insensitive, variable names within a preset are still case-sensitive. This may lead to unexpected results when using inconsistent casing. For best results, keep the casing of environment variable names consistent.
- `$penv{<variable-name>}`: Similar to `$env{<variable-name>}`, except that the value only comes from the parent environment, and never from the `environment` field. This allows you to prepend or append values to existing environment variables. For example, setting `PATH` to `/path/to/ninja/bin:$penv{PATH}` will prepend `/path/to/ninja/bin` to the `PATH` environment variable. This is needed because `$env{<variable-name>}` does not allow circular references.
- `$vendor{<macro-name>}`: An extension point for vendors to insert their own macros. CMake will not be able to use presets which have a `$vendor{<macro-name>}` macro, and effectively ignores such presets. However, it will still be able to use other presets from the same file. CMake does not make any attempt to interpret `$vendor{<macro-name>}` macros. However, to avoid name collisions, IDE vendors should prefix `<macro-name>` with a very short (preferably <= 4 characters) vendor identifier prefix, followed by a `.`, followed by the macro name. For example, the Example IDE could have `$vendor{xide.ideInstallDir}`.

Comment: I'm trying to build a mental of where/why to configure CMake in CMakeLists.txt vs. CMakePresets.json (see related https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/450867/cmake-install-directory-cmakepresets-json-vs-cmakelists-txt). Do I understand correctly: if I wanted my install-dir to have the processor, I have the choice of setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in CMakeLists.txt _or_ setting `installDir` with a hardcoded processor in CMakePresets.json? Does it just come down to "whatever suits your needs" or is there a right/wrong in choosing CMakeLists.txt vs. CMakePresets.json?

Comment: @StoneThrow The way I go about that decision is to only put things that are absolutely necessary to build the project (regardless of build environment) into the CMakeLists.txt, and everything that is a matter of opinion, style or your concrete build environment into the CMakePresets.json. The reason to do it that way is that the values in the presets can be overwritten by someone building the project, while hard-coding these things in the CMakeLists.txt often means users that want different values need to patch the build system files.

Comment: The install prefix is of the latter category, so I'd put it into the CMakePresets.json. I don't see an issue hard-coding the processor there either, as the preset will be specific to the processor regardless. In fact, I use the exact same pattern of using the preset name in the install prefix. That also has the benefit that it scales much better when adding more configurations, e.g. ones with enabled address sanitizer or other optional hardening tools. You'll find that there are so many different combinations that using the preset name for the install directory is probably the sanest option.