# Can CMake Presets be used to check for a parent environment variable or a cache variable?

Tags: cmake, cmake-presets

The following CMakePresets.json demonstrates finding a toolchain file from a path relative to parent environment variable `VCPKG_DIR`:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 20
  },
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "demo",
      "displayName": "demo",
      "description": "demo",
      "generator": "Unix Makefiles",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
      "toolchainFile": "$penv{VCPKG_DIR}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
$ VCPKG_DIR=/home/user/dev/vcpkg/ cmake --preset demo
Preset CMake variables:

  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH="/home/user/dev/vcpkg//scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/dev/cmake_learn/preset_env_or_cachevar_for_toolchain/build
$
```

However, a user (i.e. a specific user that I interact with) does not want to set any environment variables; the user wants to explicitly set the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` cache variable. CMake Presets seem to account for this cleanly: you can just specify `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`:

```
$ cmake --preset demo -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/user/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/dev/cmake_learn/preset_env_or_cachevar_for_toolchain/build
$
```

I want that when the user does not specify `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`, the CMakePresets.json will enforce that the user does specify `VCPKG_DIR` in the parent environment.
I tried adding a `conditions` clause to implement this:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 20
  },
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "demo",
      "displayName": "demo",
      "description": "demo",
      "generator": "Unix Makefiles",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
      "toolchainFile": "$penv{VCPKG_DIR}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
      "condition": {
        "type": "allOf",
        "conditions": [
          {
            "type": "notEquals",
            "lhs": "$penv{VCPKG_DIR}",
            "rhs": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This implements the desired behavior of enforcing that the user specifies `VCPKG_DIR`:

```
$ cmake --preset demo
CMake Error: Could not use disabled preset "demo"
$ VCPKG_DIR=/home/user/dev/vcpkg/ cmake --preset demo
Preset CMake variables:

  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH="/home/user/dev/vcpkg//scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/dev/cmake_learn/preset_env_or_cachevar_for_toolchain/build
$
```

..but it's not quite right: it implements that the user *must always* specify `VCPKG_DIR` in the parent environment:

```
$ cmake --preset demo -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/user/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake # undesired: CMake will fail this because VCPKG_DIR  is not defined
CMake Error: Could not use disabled preset "demo"
$ VCPKG_DIR=/path/to/foo cmake --preset demo -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/user/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/dev/cmake_learn/preset_env_or_cachevar_for_toolchain/build
$
```

Rather, I would like to implement the condition "either a parent environment variable is set or `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` must be specified" -- **is there a way to do this in CMakePresets.json?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible. As I had pointed out in my answer to your question [Is the system processor available in CMakePreset.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77930598/is-the-system-processor-available-in-cmakepreset-json) there is no way to access the value of cache variables through macro expansion in a preset.

However, wouldn't removing the condition that the `VCPKG_DIR` variable needs to be set already make the preset behave exactly as you want? If a user doesn't manually specify `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` (or `--toolchain`) on the command-line but has `VCPKG_DIR` set it will work, if `VCPKG_DIR` is set and the user doesn't specify their own toolchain file it will also work, and if a user doesn't set `VCPKG_DIR` and also doesn't specify another toolchain file. configuring the project will fail because the toolchain file at `/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake` does not exist. That at least generates an error, whereas a condition that is not satisfied would hide the preset entirely, and the user wouldn't even know that they are meant to do something to make it visible.

Comment: Thank you, and agreed: I guess simply not specifying _any_ condition "works" -- but the desired failure condition (when the user neither specifies `VCPKG_DIR` nor `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`) fails because of an inability to find the toolchain file, i.e. it fails due to coming down to CMake "base behavior" (I don't know what else to call it). I was hoping/wondering if there was a way to "intentionally enforce" it, i.e. with an intentionally-written conditional. But if the answer is "no," that's an answer too :) Thanks for this and your other recent answers to my CMake questions.

Comment: Can I ask if this picture is correct in the mental model I'm building: in CMakePresets.json, some variables that "map to" cache variables can be assigned values, for the purpose of writing the cache file, e.g. `installDir` can be assigned a value, with the result that `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` receives that value in the cache file. But nothing specified as `-D` arguments is available for "reading" during parsing of CMakePresets.json, not in `$env{}`, etc. -- is that all correct?

Comment: @StoneThrow: Exactly. It might help to know that CMake presets were introduced as a way to unify setting up CMake projects across IDEs. The json is not only parsed and interpreted by CMake, but by every IDE supporting presets. It would be nearly impossible to get any adoption if these IDEs were required to reimplement internal CMake logic to figure out the (default) values of certain cache variables before the project is even configured. Similarly, cmake has a `cmake --list-presets` mode that lists all presets. That can't know any additional args you'll later pass to cmake.

Comment: You could argue that you should be able to access cache variables if their value is explicitly set in the current preset or a preset that you're inheriting from, as at first glance that seems to be readily available even if all you're doing is parsing json. But then you get into all kind of weird edge cases if a user explicitly specifies a different value for that cache variable on the command line and optionally also for a cache variable whose value depends on the value of another one, or the project itself forcefully updates a cache entry. Should the next run update the value?